# Symbol Lookup Error in case of using perlipq software

Tags: perl

I installed the perlipq software on my Debian 6.0.6 virtual machine. When attempting to run a piece of software that depends on `perlipq` or `IPTables::IPv4::IPQueue` module, I get the following error. Any idea how to resolve this?

```
/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: 
/usr/lib/perl5/auto/IPTables/IPv4/IPQueue/IPQueue.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use a module compiled with a different build of Perl. Install it with the Perl you are actually using.

Comment: you can use whichever `perl` you want, as long as you use the same `perl` to install the module and to run your script. How did you install the module?

Comment: If I remember correctly I did perl Makefile.PL. when I do which perl it shows /usr/bin/perl. I dont think another perl is on my system.

Comment: I presume you went on to do `make`, `make test` and `make install`? and `make test` didn't give this error?! You get the error from `perl -MIPTables::IPv4::IPQueue -e1`, right?

Comment: I don't believe I did make etc.. I'll run it later today and respond backnight.

Comment: `perl Makefile.PL` "just" generates the makefile. It doesn't install anything.

Comment: `cpan IPTables::IPv4::IPQueue` would do all the steps and even install dependencies if needed.

Comment: I tried running the cpan command it looks like it is alread installed. CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 01 Mar 2013 22:06:57 GMT
IPTables::IPv4::IPQueue is up to date (1.25).

Comment: We know it's installed. We know it's a bad install. Run `cpan`, and from within, enter `force test IPTables::IPv4::IPQueue`. If that works (and only then), follow up with `force install IPTables::IPv4::IPQueue`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25448/discussion-between-chuck-and-ikegami)

Comment: I've added to the chat.

Comment: I resolved my package error by uninstalling the libpitables-ipv4-ipqueue-perl. I think the problem is that the lipiptabes-ipv4-ipqueue-perl package is not supported in squeeze for AMD64.The only available package is in wheezy and sid. However, when adding a sid repository to my apt sources list and grabbing the software I receive a bunch of errors because my stable, squeeze Debian version, doesn't include all the proper versions of the software. I'll try installing perlipq again later tonight and post my results.

Answer (score -1):

what helped me
rm -r /home/username/perl5/*  # Exercise caution with this command
apt-get install libc6-dev

Comment: Is this right? ~/perl5 has files that cause a problem? I think this should be clarified, it reads like someone trying to cause harm.

Comment: I don't see anything to indicate that the user had installed Perl modules in their home directory. From the comments, it sounds like they installed incompatible Perl module packages from their distribution.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.